# Silence typescript error "Property does not exist on type never"

Tags: typescript

This question is related to this issue with the TypeScript compiler:

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11498

The discussion ranges far and wide over how to fix the compiler but I didn't see any work arounds.

The short description of the problem is that:

```
var bar: Foo | null | undefined = null;
```

results in the type of 'bar' being narrowed to "never".  If you have an if block that sets the variable, then it widens, but a callback does not widen the type.

Here's a [playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?&q=474#code/AQ4YwGwQwZxkCKBXAXsA3gKFD4AzAewCcBTKMACwAo8kA7MALmCqoA9m6kBbAIxKIBKYAF4AfMF4ECEMnUGCsuZfmJUAblCLAAlqOAAGANy7gAQhHAAjMZ0BqO8EXYVrzdp0wAIgTol9tAxUOoJGLq7KOnjB3r4kwrykUADWYRGgAL7huFk4Wdk6dAAuAnjk-gBi0hjZOADmJEUAalAQSCRUgswwRUSFdWmZmNnuklrMVQTAAD7AXBAQM8D0ACYkeIUkK-rzEGEjWsAAjqg7JADuwMgonfs4YL4wMiQAdOdadFQARADKRVpFfqqJKUL6CYY4E4oF6EEHUdSiCRKFRRDSiESWABsznSIF4h0s6AazVa7U6GGApCKSCIdGAXxQXwyGUG6SpNLpvXarJytVA7Np%20FaMBIPIy4IO2nxaEsVHx2gA-GMiC9iS02h1hMwvgqwRDQA86E9ZG8PnKoChQpggA) if you want to see the error.

I found a workaround, but I don't like it (but it does work).

Is there a better work around?

```
class  Quz {
    foreach(func: ((x: number) => boolean)){
        for(var i = 0; i != 10;i++ ){
            var isDone = func(i);
            if(isDone) break;
        }
    }
}

interface Foo {
    getValue(): string;
}

var bar: Foo | null | undefined;

/* Is there a better way to silence the stupid error??? */
if(Math.random() < 2) {
    bar = null;
}


var quz = new Quz();

console.warn("Starting foreach")

quz.foreach(v => {
    if(v === 6){
        bar = {getValue() { return "z"}};
        return true;
    }
    return false;
})

var baz = (bar ? bar.getValue() : "?")

console.warn(baz);
```

Comment: The underlying issue is [ms/TS#9998](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998) and the workaround I see most often is to use a type assertion on the assignment, as mentioned [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998#issuecomment-524668147), and as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mMX6bN). Does that fully address the question? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz  That was exactly what I wanted.  If you could just copy that to an answer I would happily upvote it!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) TypeScript uses to narrow variables of [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types), such as when you [assign](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#assignments) a value to it, doesn't properly account for what happens when these variables are changed in [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).  This is the subject of [microsoft/TypeScript#9998](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998).  It's not computationally feasible for the compiler to follow control flow into and out of functions, so it makes some approximations.  In this case the relevant approximation is that calling functions will not have any effect on closed-over variables.

So `bar` is indeed reassigned inside the callback, but the compiler doesn't see it.  And thus it is never widened from its initial assignment to `null`.  Oops.

---

In cases like this, the "standard" workaround I've seen, as mentioned [in this comment on ms/TS#9998](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998#issuecomment-524668147), is to block the assignment narrowing by using a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions).  So you change

```
var bar: Foo | null | undefined = null;
```

to

```
var bar = null as Foo | null | undefined;
```

This doesn't change the underlying type of the `bar` variable, but it does change the *apparent* type, since `null as Foo | null | undefined` is only seen by the compiler as type `Foo | null | undefined`.  Thus `bar` is not narrowed by the assignment, and so it doesn't erroneously believe that `bar` *must* be nullish inside `(bar ? bar.getValue() : "?")`.

It's not a perfect solution, since it turns off a useful feature, but at least it lets you make progress.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECKCuAvaBvAUNT0BmB7ATgKZjAAWAFNvAHbABc055AHg9fALYBGh+AlNAC8APmhdcuEMWp8B6LApwFGANzD5oASyHQADAG4t0AISDoARgNaA1NbkZFjtRs0QAIrmqEdVWuU18+g6OCprYjK4eXgJcRGAA1kEh0AC+waloaWia1AAuvNgk3gBiEqjpAOaEuQBqYCDwhOR8DBC5+DkVQVnOYuo67CAg0JDQpbjQAD7Qg8PTNAAmhNg5hAtBaL0AjkgDhADucEjNG8CeEJKEAHT76tTkAEQAyrnquZ1KcWQPfGhoO4grngvhQVEJRPIsGFVEJBGYAGz2ZJcfpmFDQKq1eqNZqoaBEXLwfDUaAPRAPVKpJIhAlEkntRrUzBpBS04k4eoQQjdX6bfoo5BmcgojQAfj6+CumLqDSaAgYD1FPz+Z2oFykNzuwrAiECaCAA)